# How would you condense this code? -- Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a dungeon game, but and it's an 8x8 tile grid, but I need to fill all of it with wood tiles. Do you know how I could do it? I'm trying to first place 8 tiles and hen go down and place 8 more tiles.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([510, 510])
wood_floor = pygame.image.load('Desktop/Python Game 1/wood_floor.png')

x = 0
y = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, y))
    x += 64
x = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, 64))
    x += 64
x = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, 128))
    x += 64
x = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, 192))
    x += 64
x = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, 256))
    x += 64
x = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, 320))
    x += 64
x = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, 384))
    x += 64
x = 0
for i in range(8):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, 448))
    x += 64
```

Comment: Create a nested for loop.

Comment: Please wait until you can ask more question, and ask your 2nd question separately.

Comment: Instead of posting screen shots of terminal windows, please copy-paste the text instead to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `//` (floor division) operator and `%` (modulo) operator:

```py
for i in range(64):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, ((i // 8) * 64, (i % 8) * 64))
```

---

To improve the performance create a large `pygame.Surface` object and `blit` the tiles on the *Surface*:

```py
board = pygame.Surface((8*64, 8*64))
for i in range(64):
    board.blit(wood_floor, ((i // 8) * 64, (i % 8) * 64))
```

`blit` the `board` *Surface* continuously in the application loop:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    screen.blit(board, (0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Rabbid76's answer, but using the coordinates as loop variables, to avoid the extra multiplication in the loop body:

```py
for y in range(0, 8 * 64, 64):
    for x in range(0, 8 * 64, 64):
        screen.blit(wood_floor, x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked best:

```
x = 0
y = 0
for i in range(64):
    screen.blit(wood_floor, (x, y))
    x += 64
    if x == 512:
        y += 64
        x = 0
```

Comment: Every of the other answers works as well. This doesn't work any better than the other solutions. You just overcomplicated the code. You need 9 lines of code for something that can be done with 3 lines (or even less).